# Why does RxNetty use threadpools?

Tags: java, netty, nio, rx-netty

Recently I saw [io.reactivex.netty.client.PoolExhaustedException](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty/issues/503). Isn't netty supposed to run using O(1) number of threads? isn't it advertised as the async, non-blocking, using event-loop client?

if it uses thread pools then why do i need it? I can just create my own pool in 3 lines of code and use it to do blocking connections.

Comment: [This article](http://ayedo.github.io/netty/2013/06/19/what-is-netty.html) explains reasons neatly.

Comment: that article says that netty uses NIO(2) so it's doesn't need thread-per-connection. it doesn't explain why thread-pools are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception is for "connection" pool exhausted and not thread pool

Comment: You need more than one connections if your requests are not multiplexed (eg: HTTP)